# jQuery attribute contains JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

After hours of searching without result, I turn to you

The question is simple, with jQuery can I put JavaScript in an attribute?

example

```
<div id="MyDiv" data-func="
    console.log('#MyDviv[data-func] called')
"></div>
```

The ultimate goal is: I have an object that has an action to do and I would like before I do this to call a function that checks can proceed.

Example

```
<div id="MyDiv" data-action="next" data-func="
    ()=>{
        var valid = true

        /* ... */

        return valid===true;
    }
"></div>
```

code in the library

```
$('#MyDiv').on('MyEvent',function() {

    /* ... */

    var buttonAct = $(this).attr('data-action');

    var validator = $(this).attr('data-func');
    var valid=false;

    /*
      code that executes the validator and puts the result in valid
    */

    if (valid)
    buttonNextPrev (buttonAct);

});
```

Solutions like `eval` and things like that are not allowed, I need something that works like event example `onclick`

Comment: To put it simply, no, you can't. Even if you could it's not a great idea. If you already know what logic should happen at design time then this is exactly what event handlers are for.

Comment: Design is a bad idea because you would have to use eval() to run it.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  why is it not possible ?

Comment: Because you'd need to use `eval()` and you discounted that, for very good reason.

Comment: @Rory 
the problem that this event is attacked by my bookstore to all the objects that correspond to my filtor jquery, but each object has a different validator that I would have liked to write directly in the object

Comment: Without seeing a complete example of what you mean it's hard to help, but from the sound of it your best approach would be to put the common logic in an event handler and then put the unique values in the data attribute which can be read then the event fires.

Comment: Note that you could have a number of pre-written functions and put the names of those functions in the attributes. You wouldn't necessarily need eval for that.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I am interested in this proposal write the answer with details

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia Logically it wouldn't be much different than giving them a class and basing the action taken on which class it has.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, although that's kind of abusing the semantics of CSS class names... Tomayto/tomahto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Quentin notes in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380014/215552), there is no way of putting arbitrary JavaScript into an HTML attribute and executing it without using `eval` or something equivalent.

There are workarounds, however.

For instance, if you can write the functions you want ahead of time, and name them in a memorable way, and could place the *names* of the functions in the attributes. Here's an example of doing that:

```js
const other = {
  doThisToo: (me) => {
    me.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
};

document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.color = 'red';
  const fn = this.getAttribute('data-other');
  if (other[fn]) {
    other[fn](this);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="example" data-other="doThisToo">Example</button>
```

Essentially, this is just putting the name of "some other function to call" in the attribute value and using that name to look up the function in an object `other` that has the functions as properties. One could just use globally-scoped functions as well, but I prefer to pollute the global namespace as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> solutions like eval and things like that are not allowed

Then no, it isn't possible.

Any solution that would pull text from an HTML attribute and execute it as JavaScript would be *like eval* (even if you did it at one-step removed from eval itself such as with the `Function` constructor function).